# How to get the theme outside styled-components?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, styled-components

I know how to get the `theme` from components that are created using the `styled` way:

```js
const StyledView = styled.View`
    color: ${({ theme }) => theme.color};
`;
```

But how to get from **normal components** or apply it for **different properties**? Example:

`index.js`

```js
<ThemeProvider theme={{ color: 'red' }}>
    <Main />
</ThemeProvider>
```

`main.js`

```js
<View>
    <Card aCustomColorProperty={GET COLOR FROM THEME HERE} />
</View>
```

> Notice how the property that needs the theme is not called `style`

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use the `useTheme` hook since v5.0:

```
import React, { useTheme } from 'styled-components';

export function MyComponent() {
  const theme = useTheme();

  return <p style={{ color: theme.color }}>Text</p>;
}
```

You can also use the [withTheme](https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#getting-the-theme-without-styled-components) higher order component that I contributed a long time ago since v1.2:

```
import { withTheme } from 'styled-components'

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { theme } = this.props

    console.log('Current theme: ', theme);
    // ...
  }
}

export default withTheme(MyComponent)
```

---

---

---

> original response below (ignore this!)

While there is no official solution, I came up by now:

Create a Higher Order Component that will be responsable to get the current theme and pass as a prop to a component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { CHANNEL } from 'styled-components/lib/models/ThemeProvider';

export default Component => class extends React.Component {
  static contextTypes = {
    [CHANNEL]: React.PropTypes.func,
  };

  state = {
    theme: undefined,
  };

  componentWillMount() {
    const subscribe = this.context[CHANNEL];
    this.unsubscribe = subscribe(theme => {
      this.setState({ theme })
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (typeof this.unsubscribe === 'function') this.unsubscribe();
  }

  render() {
    const { theme } = this.state;

    return <Component theme={theme} {...this.props} />
  }
}
```

Then, call it on the component you need to access the `theme`:

```
import Themable from './Themable.js'
  
const Component = ({ theme }) => <Card color={theme.color} />

export default Themable(Component);
```

Comment: I am attempting to use `withTheme` on a functional component like so:

Comment: `export const circle = withTheme(({theme}) => (<circle fill={theme.circleColor} r="40" />))`

Comment: I'm getting an error that says that it's not returning a React Node, though... so I assume `withProps` doesn't currently work with functional components?

Comment: erg. typo. “so I assume `withProps`” was supposed to be “so I assume `withTheme`”. Sorry for so many comments—I accidentally hit enter on the first one, and wasn't able to delete it, and then wasn't allowed to edit it due to the 5 minute timer... and so on.

Comment: @aminimalanimal it should work fine. Is your component  working without the withTheme part? If so, open an issue here: https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues

Comment: @aminimalanimal Wait, you are creating a variable called circle and calling a circle component inside of it. The names should be different, that's probably the problem.

Comment: `circle` is a native svg element, so I doubt it'd matter if I did name my constant the same thing. That was just a simplified example though, not something I directly tried (was trying to demonstrate something that'd fit on one line). But yes, my components were working fine until I wrapped them with `withTheme`. I'll open an issue with a better description later tonight.

Comment: Thanks for your insight. It turns out that `withTheme` does indeed work on functional components; my issue was that React components absolutely **must** start with an uppercase letter, which I thought was simply a best-practice. (In the more complex example that I referenced, I wasn't actually creating a component without `withTheme`, so I was able to place it within my larger component with `{variableName}`; with `withTheme`, that syntax was no longer valid).

Answer (score 17):

You can use `useTheme` hook

```
import { useTheme } from 'styled-components';

const ExampleComponent = () => {
  const theme = useTheme();

  return (
    <View>
       <Card aCustomColorProperty={theme.color.sampleColor} />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a HOC is a good way to tackle theming. Let me share another idea using **React's** [**Context**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html).

Context allows you to pass data from a parent node to all it’s children.
Each child may choose to get access to `context` by defining `contextTypes` in the component definition.

Let's say **App.js** is your root.

```
import themingConfig from 'config/themes';
import i18nConfig from 'config/themes';
import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent';
import AnotherChild from './AnotherChild';

class App extends React.Component {
    getChildContext() {
        return {
            theme: themingConfig,
            i18n: i18nConfig, // I am just showing another common use case of context
        }
    }

    render() {
          return (
              <View>
                  <ChildComponent />
                  <AnotherChild myText="hola world" />
              </View>
          );
    }
}

App.childContextTypes = {
    theme: React.PropTypes.object,
    i18n: React.PropTypes.object
};

export default App;
```

Now our `**ChildComponent.js** who wants some theme and i18n strings

```
class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { i18n, theme } = this.context;

        return (
           <View style={theme.textBox}>
               <Text style={theme.baseText}>
                   {i18n.someText}
               </Text>
           </View>
        );
    }
}

ChildComponent.contextTypes = {
    theme: React.PropTypes.object,
    i18n: React.PropTypes.object
};

export default ChildComponent;
```

**AnotherChild.js** who only wants theme but not i18n. He might be stateless as well:

```
const AnotherChild = (props, context) {
    const { theme } = this.context;
    return (<Text style={theme.baseText}>{props.myText}</Text>);
}

AnotherChild.propTypes = {
    myText: React.PropTypes.string
};

AnotherChild.contextTypes = {
    theme: React.PropTypes.object
};

export default AnotherChild;
```

Comment: Context is great, but I had problems with it. Components all the way down the tree wasn't receiving the new context value because context does not garantee propagation: if one component doesn't update, all it's children won't update either.

Comment: I just found this article which explains the problem with Context and provides a solution: https://medium.com/@mweststrate/how-to-safely-use-react-context-b7e343eff076

It turns out that this solution is what styled-components does internally and in my answer I'm subscribing to styled-components context. Seems good. What do you think?

Comment: @BrunoLemos from my perspective your solution looks pretty good to me! We might add something like that to core or expose CHANNEL directly and add docs for this, would you mind submitting an issue with your code? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To use `withTheme` in a functional component create a Higher-order-component.

> **Higher-order-component**:
> higher-order components, or *HOCs*, are functions that take a component and output a new component after enhancing it in some manner: 
> `const EnhancedHOCComponent = hoc(OriginalReactComponent)`

### Sample withTheme in a functional Component

```
const MyButton = ({theme}) => {
const red = theme.colors.red;

return (<div  style={{ color: red}} >how are you</div>)
}`

const Button =  withTheme(MyButton);
export default Button;
```