# What is the preferred way to theme a composed component using styled-components?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

Can anyone recommend the best way to compose `styled-component`s that need to be themed?

Here's my code: https://gist.github.com/aaronmcadam/7bfd63a6bc4cfc36f9947a449c6f494a.

I have an `Avatar` component which composes an `Image` component, which is itself a `styled-component`.

If I use `Avatar.styled.js` with `<ThemeProvider>`, the theme can be successfully overridden.

If I use `Avatar.withTheme.js`, the theme can only be overridden if I use `withTheme`.

Which is the preferred way of doing things like these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from the official docs: https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/blob/master/docs/theming.md

> We export a  component that takes a theme prop. The
> theme you provide there is injected into your styled components via
> props.theme
>
> If you ever need to get the current theme outside styled components
> (e.g. inside big components), you can use the withTheme Higher Order
> Component

```
import { withTheme } from 'styled-components'

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { theme } = this.props

    console.log('Current theme: ', theme);
    // ...
  }
}

export default withTheme(MyComponent)
```

Comment: Thanks Mohamed. I'm more looking for what the preferred style is for composing themed `styled-components`

Comment: check this it might help, it explains why withTheme was created in the first place: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40796973/how-to-get-the-theme-outside-styled-components

Comment: I don't think there is a "preferred style", it depends a lot on the context of your application and what you're trying to do. Either one is fine from our perspective! (styled-components co-creator here)