# Using ThemeProvider in separate style sheets

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components, themeprovider

I've been attempting to integrate the ThemeProvider from styled-components into an existing project. But run into the error below when accessing the theme's items in a style sheet:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sidebarImage')
  10 |     315deg,
  11 |     ${p => p.bgColor1} 0%,
  12 |     ${p => p.bgColor2} 74%),
> 13 |     url(${(props) => props.theme.images.sidebarImage});
     | ^  14 |     
  15 | background-size: cover;
  16 | background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

After fiddling around a bit I found the source of the issue. In the [tutorial](https://dev.to/aromanarguello/how-to-use-themes-in-styled-components-49h) I've been following, all styled components are defined in the same file as the component that uses it (i.e. **Container** is defined in **App.js**). In the project I'm working on all styled components are defined in separate style sheets (so **Container** would be in **App.styles.js** which is then imported to **App.js**).

Moving the styled components from App.styles.js to App.js fixes the issue. However would it be possible to give the style sheets access to the Themeprovider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once I got the source of the issue It was easy to solve. Using the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40796973/how-to-get-the-theme-outside-styled-components) I've worked up this solution (though there might be a better approach).

```
import { useTheme } from "styled-components";

...

const Sidebar = (props) => {
    const theme = useTheme();

    ...

    return (
        <s.SidebarContainer theme={theme}
                            isSidebarOpen={isSidebarOpen}>
            
            <s.SidebarHeader theme={theme}>
                {sidebarHeader}
            </s.SidebarHeader>
        </s.SidebarContainer>
    )
```